# nfs mountpoint named ``share'' breaks ls and man

Tags: 11.10, nfs

I mounted a nfs server to ~/share. This works fine as long as I'm at home, where the nfs share is in reach.
Whenver I'm not, this seems to break access to all manpages. Using man (or ls in my homedir) waits forever. Checking with strace reveals that they try to access the folder called share.

Unmounting fails too. Even with -l (lazy) and -f (force).

I am asking for three things here:

- Is ``share'' a magic name? Does something like MANPATH exist, which I should avoid?
- How do I unmount without rebooting? (I already commented the share out in fstab)
- What would you suggest me to do, to have network/position based mounting of NFS shares?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions in order:

- Yes, but it is a bit more involved. Use `manpath` to see what is the path search order for manual pages and for example `MANPATH=/usr/share/man man <whatever>` to use a specific path setting
- It might not be possible to unmount without booting (this time), but in the future you should consider mounting with the intr option, i.e. `mount -t nfs -o intr host:/path ~/share` or similarly in fstab: `host:/path  /home/user/share  nfs  intr`. Please see `man 5 nfs` for further information (if you continue have problems, see the `soft` and `timeo` options).
- Try the above options, but if they fail, you could try CIFS or sshfs instead of nfs